# A br0 bridge interface appeared and mess up my network config

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, bridge

## Problem

This afternoon, I launched my openSUSE Leap 42.1 like everyday and then I quickly note that my networking was'nt working correctly.

A quick `ifconfig` show me that a new `br0` interface show up. I never had a bridge before.

The `br0` bridge (virtual) interface is DHCP and capturing my `eth0` (physical) interface. With this configuration only a few website are working like (google.con, youtube.com, netvibe.com) but very few all other website instantly show a page telling me there is no network.

So I tried to down the `br0` bridge and switch my `eth0` to DHCP or a static adress in my local network, but I can't reah Internet this way.

(It seems teh same happened with br1 and my wlan0 iterface).

I'm pretty sure my router is working because I can connect to the Internet via my smarphone or my Windows 10 OS.

I don't know how the bridge shows up and mess up my network connection.

## Tries

I tried :

- down br0 and put eth0 in dhcp or static address
- reboot several times
- restart network service `sudo systemctl restart network.service`
- clean/void web-browser cache

## Network

- Network : 192.168.1.0/24
- Router : 192.168.1.254
- Random DHCP address get by the bridge : 192.168.1.65

Answer (score 0):

I still d'ont understand why I can't user my `eth0` directly in static or DHCP but I find how to have Internet back!

I tried to ping 8.8.8.8 (google DNS) and saw it worked and next a www.google.com that didn't work so I knew I had a DNS problem.

In fact I think wicked network deamon mess up and I didn't receive my route and DNS config via DHCP. So I had to put my router ip address manually in the ifcfg-br0 and resolv.conf files.

I now have Internet